# Why does Ayaka Ohashi have the nickname "Hego-chin"?

Tags: voice-acting

*[Ayaka Ohashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayaka_%C5%8Chashi)* is a Japanese voice actress (*seiyu*). She has nicknames such as "*Hasshī*" and "*Hego-chin*".

The word "*Hasshī* " is thought to be derived from her family name "*O**hashi***" .
However, there is no character anywhere in her name that could be the source of the sound "*Hego-chin*".

These days, she's known as "*Hego*". "*Hego*" is probably a shortened version of "*Hego-chin*".

> Why does Ayaka Ohashi have the nickname "Hegochin"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Her Japanese Wiki page tells us the origin of that nickname:

> **愛称**
>
> 愛称の一つである「へごちん」は、2013年にweb番組『五十嵐裕美のチャンネルはオープンソースでっ！』にゲスト出演した際、「頭へ ゴチン」を「頭を ヘゴチン」と読み間違えたことが由来。さらに省略されて「へご」とも呼ばれるようになった。

My translation and my explanation in the parentheses:

> Nickname
>
> One of her nicknames "Hego-chin" came from an incident that took place in 2013 when Ohashi made a guest appearance in [Igarashi Hiromi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiromi_Igarashi) (another Japanese voice actress)'s web series *Igarashi Hiromi's Channel is Open Source!* In the show Ohashi misspoke and mistakenly said "*hegochin* the head" (which is nonsensical) where she should've said "gochin to the head". She has also been called "Hego", a shorter version of "Hego-chin".

「ゴチン」(gochin) is an onomatopoeic word that describes the sound of a large object hitting someone's head. 「頭へゴチン」means to use something to hit the head in the fashion of "gochin". Here 「へ」is a particle indicating direction. The kana is usually pronounced "he" in words, but as a particle it should be pronounced "e". So the correct reading of that phrase was "atama e gochin", but Ohashi thought 「へゴチン」 was all together a word, so she pronounced it as "hegochin". Another tricky thing that led to her mistake was the hiragana 「へ」 and its katakana 「ヘ」 look alike.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It was very difficult to explain "Hegochin" to non-Japanese speakers, but your answer will be helpful.